# vscode build from source. Cannot start tests after clone repo

Tags: automated-tests, visual-studio-code

VSCode Version:

Version 1.15.1

OS Version:

ubuntu 16.04

Steps to Reproduce:

install Linux dependencies
clone repo
install all using ./scripts/npm.sh install --arch=x64
run tests ./scripts/test.sh --debug (and without debug, it's doesn't matter)
after downloading electron, starting devTools with error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/Documents/vscode-dev/vscode/out/vs/loader'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/user/Documents/vscode-dev/vscode/.build/electron/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at initLoader (/home/user/Documents/vscode-dev/vscode/test/electron/renderer.js:25:11)
    at EventEmitter.ipcRenderer.on (/home/user/Documents/vscode-dev/vscode/test/electron/renderer.js:263:2)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
```

folders and file `vscode/out/vs/loader` doesn't exist.
try to find info for this error, but fale. Try to reinstall all, reclone all, used gulp clean - it did't help me.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build first - after running `./scripts/npm.sh install`, run `npm run compile`. Then, `./scripts/test.sh`.